# Tomcat SSL https port issues

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, basic-authentication

At the moment Im trying to improve my tomcat know how. Im trying to set up tomcat with SSL.
The idea is that I got the path with /app which doesnt need any authorisation, and the path /admin, where basis authentication is needed. I guess Its just a lack of general knowhow about SSL, that I cant understand what happens.

When I use the url `http://localhost:8080/myapp/app/` it works and it shows my page. Now I change /app to /admin. After that my url is `https://localhost/myapp/admin` and it doesnt work, because the 8443 port is missing. I dont understand why does it automatically change to https but the port is missing after that? What is my problem and how can I solve it?

Any help is highly appreciated :)

My server.xml:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on"/>

<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

<Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
            />

    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="${catalina.home}/myapp.keystore"
               keystorePass="histackoverflow"/>

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />

        <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
              unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                   prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
                   pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>

        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

My web.xml looks like that:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApp REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>main.ch.myapp.resource.app</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Myapp REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app-api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApp Admin REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>main.ch.myapp.resource.admin</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyApp Admin REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin-api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>MyApp Admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/admin-api/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change to https is done because of `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` included in `<security-constraint>`.

Take a look at: 
[The Java EE 6 Tutorial, Volume I. Specifying Security Constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncbk/index.html) 
[The Java EE 6 Tutorial, Volume I. Specifying a Secure Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncbm/index.html)

> **Specifying a Secure Connection**
>
> A user data constraint (`TutorialUser-data-constraint` in the
>   deployment descriptor) contains the `transport-guarantee` element. A
>   user data constraint can be used to require that a protected transport
>   layer connection such as HTTPS (HTTP over SSL) be used for all
>   constrained URL patterns and HTTP methods specified in the security
>   constraint. The choices for transport guarantee include CONFIDENTIAL,
>   INTEGRAL, or NONE. If you specify CONFIDENTIAL or INTEGRAL as a
>   security constraint, it generally means that the use of SSL is
>   required, and that type of security constraint applies to all requests
>   that match the URL patterns in the web resource collection and not
>   just to the login dialog box.

Moreover, I suppose that the port 8443 is not available because you do not have Tomcat configured to use SSL. 
At the following link you can find a nice how-to about configuring SSL support on Tomcat:

[Apache Tomcat 7. SSL/TLS Configuration HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

--- EDIT (server.xml config was posted) ---

To be redirected to port 8443 you need to change the connector configuration as shown below:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443" />
```

[Apache Tomcat 7. The AJP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html#Common_Attributes)

> **redirectPort**
>
> If this Connector is supporting non-SSL requests, and a request is
>   received for which a matching `security-constraint` requires SSL
>   transport, Catalina will automatically redirect the request to the
>   port number specified here.

Comment: port 8443 is available when I add it. But can I configure that it switches automatically the port when im on https?

Comment: @Andy I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. The port where you get redirected when changing to https, is the one configured in the redirectPort attribute of the Connector. You should get a url like this: https://localhost:8443/myapp/admin  Can you post your server.xml configuration?

Comment: Ty for your help. I added the server.xml. You did understand me right I guess. When Im adding 8443 to my url, it works. But when I just get redirected to https:// after changing the url to /admin, the port doesnt change to 8443.

Comment: @Andy add `redirectPort="8443"` to `<Connector port="8080" ...` I'll edit my answer to add this change.

Comment: great, ty!:) this was the change I was looking for

Comment: Can an exception be made to _not_ redirect connections coming from `localhost`?

Comment: @MikhailT. AFAIK it's not possible with security constraints, as the documentation states that "A web resource collection is a list of URL patterns (the part of a URL **after** the host name and port which you want to constrain)". But, you can post it as a new question. Maybe someone can help you.